# new in Objective-C in init - how to handle std::bad_alloc?

Tags: c++, objective-c++

I need to wrap a c++ object inside an Objective-C class - initially I did that by putting the C++ objects inside the `@implementation` in the `.mm` file like this:

MyObjCClass.h:

```
@interface MyObjCClass : NSObject
@end
```

MyObjCClass.mm:

```
@implementation MyObjCClass {
    MyCppClass member;
}
@end
```

Sadly I had to give this up since this code is also used in a project which targets 32-bit architectures and thus this feature is not supported. So I did a forward struct declaration, the struct is defined in the `.mm` file and wraps the C++ object:

MyObjCClass.h:

```
struct MyObjCClassPrivate;

@interface MyObjCClass : NSObject {
    MyObjCClassPrivate* memberPrivate;
}

-(void)dealloc;
-(id)init;
@end
```

MyObjCClass.mm:

```
struct MyObjCClassPrivate {
    MyCppClass member;
}

@implementation MyObjCClass

-(void)dealloc
{
    delete memberPrivate;
    memberPrivate = nullptr;
}

-(id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        memberPrivate = new MyObjCClassPrivate; // what happens if new throws std::bad_alloc ?
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

The question is - should I care if the allocation with new fails? What are the consequences (apart from the exception being thrown?) - do I need to do some additional cleanup for the Ojbective-C class instance?

I dont want to put the c++ stuff in the header since this class is also used by plain Objective-C code, which then fails to compile.

Comment: Can the downvoter explain the issue with this question?

Comment: Two possible reasons for `std::bad_alloc` to be thrown: (1) out of memory and (2) corrupt heap.  Recovering from either is usually impossible.  As for the down vote my guess: page length question that could have been asked in 3 or 4 lines eg _"Is it possible to recover from `std::bad_alloc` ?"_ and a short main program.

Comment: @RichardCritten the question in not if it's possible to recover from `std::bad_alloc` - my intent was to ask what happens if an Objective-C++ code throws a C++ exception which then gets passed to Objective-C - do the standard `@try` handlers works, or is something else needed for C++ exceptions. But apparently I did not make myself clear.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis did you tried to handle C++ exceptions with @try?